# Scraping with python from specific location

Tags: python, web, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information from a website, bear in mind that I'm new to python.

My current code is this

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page1 = requests.get('snip')
page2 = requests.get('snip')
page3 = requests.get('snip')
page4 = requests.get('snip')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```

I need to extract the number (currently 37) from here:

```
<div class='count col-xs-4'>
<p><strong>37</strong> <br class='hidden-md hidden-lg'/>followers</p>
</div>
```

However I'm not too sure how to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use BeautifulSoup (bs4) among numerous other tools to accomplish this. Try that out, as it's quite easy to follow the tutorial. If you still are lost, I can help you out more.

Comment: Ok so I'm using bs4 now but I have an issue.

`
<div class='clearfix user-counts text-center-not-md text-center-not-lg row '>
<div class='count col-xs-4'>
<p><strong>4</strong> <br class='hidden-md hidden-lg'/>posts</p>
</div>
<div class='count col-xs-4'>
<p><strong>37</strong> <br class='hidden-md hidden-lg'/>followers</p>
</div>
<div class='count col-xs-4'>
<p><strong>470</strong> <br class='hidden-md hidden-lg'/>following</p>`

I need to extract the numbers from following, followers, etc, but they don't have IDs and they have the same class.

Comment: But that is perfect! Use soup.find_all("div", "count col-xs-4"), and iterate through the resulting list. Use the .contents method to get the text within

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xpath to fetch the information. The following should work.

```
tree =  html.fromstring(page1.text)   
number = tree.xpath('//*[@class="count col-xs-4"]/p/strong/text()')
```